# Sort by ascending number order

Tags: powershell

```
$var_1text = $var_2text = $var_17text = $null
Get-Variable -Name var_*
```

I get the following output : 1-17-2

```
var_1text
var_17text
var_2text
```

But I want the following output : 1-2-17

```
var_1text
var_2text
var_17text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Sort-Object` cmdlet:

```
Get-Variable -Name var_* |Sort-Object { ($_.Name -replace "[^\d]","") -as [int] }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry I just edited the post, in fact there is more text behind the variable.

Comment: Yes, I saw. Updated answer to strip out any non-digit from the variable name in the sorting algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Along the same lines

```
Get-Variable -Name var_*  | Select-Object *,@{L="NameIndex";E={[void]($_.Name -match '\d+');[int]$Matches[0]}} | Sort-Object NameIndex
```

You can create a calculated property that only contains the number portion. Cast it to `[int]` and sort on that property. This would be especially useful if you need to refer to this more than once in the code as supposed to recalling the regex.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry I just edited the post, in fact there is more text behind the variable.